# Producing Nested Lists for each Value in a List

Tags: python, list, nested

How is it possible to make each value in a list into its own list?

Say we're given:

```
Numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I would suspect that a for or while loop would do the trick:

```
for number in Numbers:
    Numbers.append([number])
```

but this seems to not satisfy what I'd like to do.

Comment: You are iterating through Numbers but you append Numbers at the same time. The loop will never end. Try to create another empty list to store your outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a list comprehension:

```
print([[i] for i in Numbers])
```

Or use `map`:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: [x], Numbers)))
```

Output:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
```